# PM2 Process Stops After Some Days / Time Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pm2

I've a problem with my react and node application, in production, when i'm using the following commands to run my node app in production:

`pm2 start app.js --name=MyAppName`
`pm2 save --force`

after executing the above commands, server runs successfully, that is perfect.
but after some days pm2 process stops automatically without giving any logs

please help me about the above issue,
I'm so worried about this, Thanks